# Trading fractional shares with Backtesting.py

Tags: python, share, trading, back-testing

'UserWarning: Some prices are larger than initial cash value. Note that fractional trading is not supported. If you want to trade Bitcoin, increase initial cash, or trade μBTC or satoshis instead (GH-134).'

How can I implement trading of fractional shares (BTC in my personal case) in backtesting.py?

I want to trade fraction of BTC in order to backtest my strategy starting from a realistic amount of money.

Comment: What have you tried? I guess you've written some code in order to get that error message, so maybe you could add that to your question and describe what you were expecting it to do instead?